# Lotus Notes Design elements not refreshing

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula, lotus-designer

I recently made changes and created two forms in a database residing in a production server. When I sent out the link, the users are getting this error:

> Unable to create document, database does not contain design.

I suspect that the database residing in their Workspace is not getting the latest design elements (not in-sync). I tried asking one user to remove the database from her Workspace, sent the link to the database to open it again, and click on another link which I provided to open up the two forms and she was able to access the forms.

May I ask if there's any other way I can do for them to not delete it from their Workspace and re open it again so it will get the latest design elements? Should I request the Notes Administrator to perform some codes in the console?

Comment: Hi, if they have the db already open, they need to close the db and reopen it probably. If there is more than 1 server or local replicas involved, it may take some time until the change is propagated.

Comment: Is there a way where they should no longer re-open up the database? I am sending them the ?openform url link (which opens the database by default and open the form) but they are getting the error.

Comment: There's also File->Application->Refresh Design

Answer (score 0):

Form designs are cached by the Notes client, presumably to aid performance. As far as I know, it's not possible to disable the caching.

If users have a database open when you modify or add forms, it's usually necessary for them to close and reopen the database to see the design changes, but they shouldn't ever have to remove the database from the workspace and re-add it. I don't think there's any way to avoid having to reopen the database.

I have seen a problem affecting several users at one customer where Notes wouldn't update its design cache, no matter what they did inside the client. The only solution I found in that case was to close Notes, delete a file named "cache.ndk" from the root of the Notes data directory, then restart Notes. It's been 2 or more years since this last occurred, so it might have been fixed in some version of Notes.